# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. On Expo / GraphQL Apollo client

Tags: react-native, graphql, expo, apollo

I am running into a TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. This is on Expo / React Native with an Apollo client.

I have the following GraphQL query

```
const GET_VIDEOS = gql`
    {
      users(limit: 3) {
        userVideos {
          muxPlaybackId
          videoQuestion {
            questionText
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `;
```

And I create the following component:

```
export const VideoData = (ref) => {
    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_VIDEOS); 

    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

    console.log(data);

    return (<Video
            ref={ref}
            source={{ uri: data.users[0].userVideos[0].muxPlaybackId}}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={false}
            resizeMode="cover"
            usePoster={true}
            shouldPlay
            isLooping
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
        >
        </Video>
    );
}
```

It seems that the problem is coming from the following line:

```
source={{ uri: data.users[0].userVideos[0].muxPlaybackId}}
```

But how else do I access this muxPlaybackId string? This is the only value I need for the Video source.

For completeness, this is my GraphQL result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "userVideos": [
          {
            "muxPlaybackId": "e6ZNh139bm2Poz5xoPl4V4016fnRCPWcZbkrTxg3Ocys",
            "videoQuestion": {
              "questionText": "What do you miss most about normal life?"
            }
          },
          {
            "muxPlaybackId": "DeygMKplfbg4Ye6PtCiFDgMFI01AEBp1tnfoVD9k401Ws",
            "videoQuestion": {
              "questionText": "What is your favorite color?"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "userVideos": []
      },
      {
        "userVideos": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue has anything to do with how you are accessing the `muxPlaybackId`. The runtime appears to be complaining about *assigning* something, not *accessing*.

To be sure, though, instead of using an expression to access the `muxPlaybackId`, try hardcoding it and see if you have the same problem:

```js
source={{ uri: "e6ZNh139bm2Poz5xoPl4V4016fnRCPWcZbkrTxg3Ocys" }}
```

If this still produces the error, then I would look at the `Video` component and see what attributes you are allowed to set.